# Perform multiple updates at once via Twitter4J on sincle account

Tags: exception, authentication, twitter4j

The Java class [here](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/tweets/UpdateStatus.java) works fine for me. My problem is that I can't perform more than 1 updates at once. In fact, Java throws a try-catch exception every time it reaches the following lines for second time:

```
try {
    // get request token.
    // this will throw IllegalStateException if access token is already available
    RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
    ...
```

As you can imagine, the class is being called multiple times within a for loop. So, any ideas?

PS: Hope not having messed up my question. :D

Comment: The example is just for one entire run-through with an entire OAuth2 flow. If you're trying to do that in a loop, it must fail. These examples are just "plain stupid" and not for production use. Please provide us your entire code, I think you didn't just copy that.

Comment: As I said, my code is exactly the same as in the link provided. I have also added a standard properties file, namely "twitter4j.properties", at the root of the classpath directory. That's all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done like this (pseudo code)

```
GetAccessToken
AuthenticateUser

Loop
   doUpdate

CleanUp
```

Twitter4J "holds" a session for the authenticated user, so starting with a new, different user needs a new instance of the Twitter4J.

Comment: Great. So first I had to pass all twitters at once and then call command `Status status = twitter.updateStatus(args[i]);` multiple times, i.e. within a for loop. Not sure, however, whether this solution could work when my java application never stops running. I have to check that...